# Clear dynamically created div

Tags: javascript

I want to clear a dynamically created div , following is the function where div is created: I have tried like:

```
jQuery('#sel').html('');
 $( ".sel" ).empty();
```

but nothing helps

```
       function constructor_obj(parent, title, address, pincode,village,mobile,owner, specs) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.title = title;
        this.address = address;
        this.pincode = pincode;
        this.village = village;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.specs = specs;

        var div = document.createElement('sel');
        div.style = "width:auto";
        div.className = "w3-card-4";
        div.innerHTML = '\
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:auto">\
<div class="w3-container">\
    <h1 class="title"><b>Dr. Abc</b></h1>\
</div>\
<div class="w3-container">\
    <h2 class="specialty">Specialty :<b> Physiotherapist</b></h2>\
    <hr>\
    <p class="address">Address :<b> Marketing and Advertising. Seeking a new job and new opportunities.</b></p>\
      <p class="pincode">Fee Details:500-600rs</p>\
      <p class="village">Fee Details:500-600rs</p>\
      <p class="mobile">Fee Details:500-600rs</p>\
      <p class="owner">Fee Details:500-600rs</p>\
      \
</div>\
<button class="w3-btn-block w3-dark-grey">More Details</button>\
  ';
        this.parent.appendChild(div);
        div.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerHTML = this.title;
        div.getElementsByClassName('specialty')[0].innerHTML = this.specs;
        div.getElementsByClassName('address')[0].innerHTML = this.address;
        div.getElementsByClassName('pincode')[0].innerHTML = this.pincode;
        div.getElementsByClassName('village')[0].innerHTML = this.village;
        div.getElementsByClassName('mobile')[0].innerHTML = this.mobile;
        div.getElementsByClassName('owner')[0].innerHTML = this.owner;
        this.parent="";
    }
```

I am calling this function here:

```
function generatefilterrecord() {

      for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
        obj = new constructor_obj(document.body,name[i],address[i], pincode[i],village[i],mobile[i],owner[i],spec[i]);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: you used html() and empty() but haven't used remove()! then try it now. https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: i have tried with remove() also but problem is that var div is not globbaly declared and if i declare globally then it is not working

Comment: `$(".w3-card-4").remove();` should remove your div.

Comment: Thank you bro this one worked: $(".w3-card-4").remove();

Comment: Thanks for removing that code snippet... it was crashing the page for me.

Comment: Why are you disfiguring your question by removing the code body? It will make this question invalid and can be closed.

Answer (score 0):

`var div = document.createElement('sel');` actually creates a tag that looks like this `<sel></sel>`. What you really want to do is this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'sel';
```

This will result in a tag like `<div id="sel"></div>` and now you can access it using standard JQuery ID notation as in `$('#sel')` (as well as run all your other JS on it). To clear it of everything, just do `div.innerHTML = ''`

Note that in order to see it at all you'll need to get it onto the page somehow by adding it to another element's `innerHTML` or similar (I didn't check to see if you did this, if you did, ignore this part, I'm just being safe).

Comment: thanks for the answer @peter but here problem is var div = document.createElement('div'); is not a global variable , i am using it in some function and now i want to clear it outside this function

Comment: i have tried with jQuery('#sel').html(''); but it didnt helped

Comment: Maybe you can use `document.getElementById('sel')` (after using my above example code so the ID actually is "sel") to get the div element once it's in the DOM? If its never making it to the DOM then you've got a different issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has two ways to get the dom : one is to get by id, the other using class;
but  you are not the two above. You can add the id in html, or use the class .  the way you get the dom ： jQuery('#sel').html(''); $( ".sel" ).empty() are not the right way. you can choose the second one. just like this:

$( ".w3-card-4" ).remove();

and beside
var div = document.createElement('sel');
change to
var div = document.createElement('div');
msut be better.

Comment: jQuery selectors are not limited to id and class. There are many of those selectors, which we can use to select dom elements. https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Element.innerHTML`

> The Element.innerHTML property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing
>   the element's descendants. [More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```js
document.getElementById('sel').innerHTML = '';
```

```html
<div id="sel">some content here</div>
```

Comment: @abc Hi, please make sure your code is visible in your question :)